# How do I make my collectionView UICollectionViewCell a dynamic height?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview and the cells in the collectionview are stretching their height. I used UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout so similar questions asked on this site did not seem to apply.

Here is where I create my UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

```
 private func configureLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(400))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    }
```

Here is the View I am trying to display in the cell.

```
class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier = String(describing: PostCell.self)
    
    private lazy var textPost : TextPostView = {
        let textPost = TextPostView()
        
        textPost.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(textPost)
        
        textPost.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        textPost.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        textPost.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textPost.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return textPost
    }()
    
    private lazy var mediaPost : MediaPostView = {
        let mediaPost = MediaPostView()
        
        mediaPost.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(mediaPost)
        
        mediaPost.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        mediaPost.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mediaPost.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        mediaPost.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return mediaPost
    }()
    
    private lazy var eventPost : EventPostView = {
        let eventPost = EventPostView()
        
        eventPost.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(eventPost)
        
        eventPost.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        eventPost.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        eventPost.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        eventPost.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return eventPost
    }()
    
    func setData(_ presentable: PostPresentable) {
        switch presentable.type {
        case .text:
            eventPost.isHidden = true
            mediaPost.isHidden = true
            textPost.isHidden = false
            textPost.setData(presentable)
        case .media:
            eventPost.isHidden = true
            mediaPost.isHidden = false
            textPost.isHidden = true
            mediaPost.setData(presentable)
        case .event:
            eventPost.isHidden = false
            mediaPost.isHidden = true
            textPost.isHidden = true
            eventPost.setData(presentable)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the TextPostView that I display in the cell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TextPostView: UIView {
    
    lazy var headerView: PostHeaderView = {
        let headerView = PostHeaderView()
        headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(headerView)
        
        let margin: CGFloat = 2
        headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
        headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
        headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
        
        return headerView
    }()
    
    lazy var descriptionView: UILabel = {
        let description = UILabel()
        description.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        description.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        description.numberOfLines = 0
        
        
        let headerViewLayoutGuide = headerView.layoutGuide(self)
        
        addSubview(description)
        
        let margin: CGFloat = 8
        
        description.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerViewLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
        description.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor,constant: margin).isActive = true
        description.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -margin).isActive = true
        return description
    }()
    
    lazy var footerView: PostFooterView = {
        let footer = PostFooterView()
        footer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(footer)
        
        let descriptionViewLayoutGuide = descriptionView.layoutGuide(self)
        
        footer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionViewLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        footer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        footer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        footer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        return footer
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        initialize()
    }
    
    private func initialize() {
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
    
    func setData(_ presentable: PostPresentable) {
        headerView.setData(presentable.header)
        footerView.setData(presentable.footer)
        descriptionView.text = presentable.description
    }
}
```

The PostHeaderView that the post uses

```
import Foundation

import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class PostHeaderView: UIView {
    
    private static let horizontalMargin: CGFloat = 8
    private static let iconHeight: CGFloat = 20
    
    private lazy var date: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(label)
        
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: PostHeaderView.horizontalMargin).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var flairsContainer: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .trailing
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let dateLayoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        let shareLayoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        
        addLayoutGuide(dateLayoutGuide)
        addLayoutGuide(shareLayoutGuide)
        addSubview(stackView)
        
        
        dateLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: date.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        shareLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shareButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shareLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PostHeaderView.iconHeight).isActive = true
        
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private lazy var title: UILabel = {
        let title = UILabel()
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        title.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
    
        
        let avatarLayoutGuide = avatar.layoutGuide(self)
        addSubview(title)
        
        title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatarLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: PostHeaderView.horizontalMargin).isActive = true
        title.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatarLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return title
    }()
    
    private lazy var subHeader: UILabel = {
        let subHeader = UILabel()
        subHeader.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        subHeader.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        
        let titleLayoutGuide = title.layoutGuide(self)
        addSubview(subHeader)
        
        subHeader.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        subHeader.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return subHeader
    }()
    
    private lazy var checkMark: UIImageView = {
        let checkMark = UIImageView()
        checkMark.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let image = UIImage(named: "VerifiedBadge")
        checkMark.image = image
        
        let subHeaderLayoutGuide = subHeader.layoutGuide(self)
        addSubview(checkMark)
        
        checkMark.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subHeaderLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        checkMark.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subHeaderLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return checkMark
    }()
    
    private lazy var menuButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu"), for: .normal)
        
        addSubview(button)
        
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -PostHeaderView.horizontalMargin).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PostHeaderView.iconHeight).isActive = true
        
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var shareButton: UIButton = {
        let shareButton = UIButton()
        
        shareButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let buttonImage = UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        shareButton.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        shareButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
        
        let menuLayoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        addLayoutGuide(menuLayoutGuide)
        addSubview(shareButton)
        
        menuLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        shareButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        shareButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        shareButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        
        return shareButton
    }()
    
    private lazy var avatar: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        let imageViewSize: CGFloat = 52
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageViewSize / 2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        let dateLayoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        addLayoutGuide(dateLayoutGuide)
        addSubview(imageView)
        
        dateLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: date.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageViewSize).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: PostHeaderView.horizontalMargin).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    func setData(_ presentable: PostHeaderPresentable) {
        date.text = presentable.date
        avatar.sd_setImage(with: presentable.avatarImageUrl)
        title.text = presentable.title
        addFlairs(presentable.flairs)
        menuButton.isHidden = false
        shareButton.isHidden = false
        if let subheadline = presentable.subheadline {
            subHeader.isHidden = subheadline.text.isEmpty
            subHeader.text = subheadline.text
            checkMark.isHidden = !subheadline.verified
        } else {
            checkMark.isHidden = true
            subHeader.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    
    private func addFlairs(_ flairImages: [UIImage]) {
        flairsContainer.removeAllArrangedSubviews()
        for flairImage in flairImages {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.image = flairImage
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            
            flairsContainer.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
            
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PostHeaderView.iconHeight).isActive = true
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PostHeaderView.iconHeight).isActive = true
        }
    }
    
}
```

The PostFooterView

```
class PostFooterView: UIView {
    
    private static let horizontalMargin: CGFloat = 8
    private static let verticalMargin: CGFloat = 16
    
    private lazy var location: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(label)
        
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -PostFooterView.horizontalMargin).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -PostFooterView.verticalMargin).isActive = true
        
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var likeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let likeImageSelected = UIImage(named: "Like")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let likeImage = UIImage(named: "LikeStroke")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.setImage(likeImageSelected, for: .selected)
        button.setImage(likeImage, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.black
        
        addSubview(button)
        
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: PostFooterView.horizontalMargin).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -PostFooterView.verticalMargin).isActive = true
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var dislikeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let dislikeImageSelected = UIImage(named: "Dislike")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let dislikeImage = UIImage(named: "DislikeStroke")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.setImage(dislikeImageSelected, for: .selected)
        button.setImage(dislikeImage, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.black
        
        addSubview(button)
        let likeButtonLayoutGuide = likeButton.layoutGuide(self)
        
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likeButtonLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likeButtonLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var navButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let navigateImage = UIImage(named: "Navigate")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.setImage(navigateImage, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Navigate", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.black
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        
        addSubview(button)
        
        let likeButtonLayoutGuide = likeButton.layoutGuide(self)
        
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor).isActive = true
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: PostFooterView.horizontalMargin).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likeButtonLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        
        return button
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    

    
    func setData(_ presentable: PostFooterPresentable) {
        location.text = presentable.location
        navButton.isHidden = !presentable.showNavigation
        likeButton.isSelected = presentable.reaction == .like
        dislikeButton.isSelected = presentable.reaction == .dislike
    }
}
```

[Here is a screenshot of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvFf8.png)